# Git get diff from two files

Tags: git, version

So I have a project localy, and the same project is also online on a FTP, but someone made some modifications online on the FTP on a css file, how do I see which modification he made?

I copy the files from the FTP to my local project, like overwrite them and than do a git diff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to overwrite anything – if all you need is the diff output, use `git diff` this way:

```
git diff original.css modified.css
```

It works exactly like the traditional `diff` tool:

```
diff -u original.css modified.css
```